# How to see the fact that the curve is the segment between $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $(y_1,...,y_n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, curves

It says that:

If $C = {x_1 + t(y_1- x_1),...,x_n + t(y_n- x_n);t ∈[0,1]}$ then C is the segment between $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $( y_1,...,y_n)$

But how to see the fact? It seems to be not such intuitive. Could someone explain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As vectors, $v = v_0+t(v_1-v_0)$ says that the position $v$ is a starting point $v_0$ plus a multiple of (t) the direction $(v_1-v_0)$ between $v_0$ and $v_1$. When t = 0 you are at $v_0$, when t = 1 you are at $v_1$ and if t is between 0 and 1 you are somewhere in between $v_0$ and $v_1$.

Comment: What *characterizes* a straight line? A fixed slope and a start and end point, right? Can you find these in the equation given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite as 
$$C(t)  = [(1-t) x_1 + t y_1, \ldots , (1-t) x_n + t y+n],
$$
then for $t = 0$, you can see that $C(0) = x$; and for $t = 1$, you can see that $C(1) = y$. And for $t = 0.5$, you can see that $C(0.5)$ is the average of $x$ and $y$. The same argument goes for any number: $C$ represents a weighted average between the two points.

Now it may not be obvious that the set of all weighted averages constituted a line, but in $n$ dimensions, what *is* your notion of what constitutes a line? Once you tell us what would convince you something is a line, we can perhaps connvince you that the set of all $C(t)$, as $t$ ranges over the reals, actually *is* one of these. (For this to be true, however, you need that $x \ne y$.)

Comment: Thus when we change $t$ from 0 to 1, actually we passed all the points that on the line that connects x and y. And then we have drawn a line between x and y. Is that correct?

Comment: As we change $t$ from $0$ to $1$ we pass through all points of the line segment between $x$ and $y$, yes; values of $t$ less than $0$ correspond to points on the side of $x$ that's farther from $y$; values of $t$ correspond to points on the side of $y$ that's farther from $x$.